# Buttons with the same javascript code do different things

Tags: javascript

```js
var toDoList = document.querySelector('.toDoList');
var acceptInput = document.querySelector('.acceptInput');
var mainButton = document.querySelector('.mainButton');
mainButton.addEventListener('click', function (){
    //Make new Li
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');
    const liContent = document.createTextNode(acceptInput.value + "      ");

    //Make done and x buttons
        const doneButton = document.createElement('button');
        const xButton = document.createElement('button');
        //What do the buttons say?
        doneButton.innerHTML = "Done";
        xButton.innerHTML = "X";
        //Program the button
        doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            newLi.remove();
        })
        xButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            newLi.remove();
        })
        //Add the buttons to the li
        newLi.appendChild(doneButton);
        newLi.appendChild(xButton);
        //Add the user input to it
        newLi.appendChild(liContent);
        //Add the li to the ul
        toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
        toDoList.appendChild(doneButton)
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="tdlist.css">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
</head>
<div>
<body>
    <input class="acceptInput" type="text" placeholder="What do you want to do?">
    <br><br>
    <button class="mainButton">Submit</button>
    <br><br>
    <ul class="toDoList">
        
    </ul>
</body>
</div>
<script src="tdlist.js"></script>
</html>
```

I am making a to-do list, where each li in the list is gonna include a 'X'or delete button and a 'Done' button. I have plans to differ them in the future, but for now, I just want them both to delete their parent list element. I added the same code to both these buttons. However, the 'X' button works properly, but the 'Done' button deletes the entire ul instead of its parent li. Here is the code:

```
    //Make new Li
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');
    const liContent = document.createTextNode(acceptInput.value + "      ");
    //Make done and x buttons
        const doneButton = document.createElement('button');
        const xButton = document.createElement('button');
        //What do the buttons say?
        doneButton.innerHTML = "Done";
        xButton.innerHTML = "X";
        //Program the button
        doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            doneButton.parentNode.remove();
        })
        xButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
            xButton.parentNode.remove();
        })
    //Add the user input to it
    newLi.appendChild(liContent);
    //Add the buttons to the li
    newLi.appendChild(doneButton);
    newLi.appendChild(xButton);
    //Add the li to the ul
    toDoList.appendChild(newLi);
    toDoList.appendChild(doneButton)
```

I have also tried `.parentElement` instead of `.parentNode` but the results are the same.

Comment: Why not call `newLi.remove()` directly ?

Comment: Looking at your code I can't really see why it's not working like you intended. Would you be able to edit your question and make it a snippet, so we can see it executing?

Comment: beside adding deleting the xbutton parent node, try to do it with the target. ```doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            event.target.parentNode.remove();
        })``` if it will not work do ```console.log(event.target.parentNode)``` inside the function and check what you are getting.. check if the parent is really the element you want to remove

Comment: @melancia I edited the code to give a snippet.

Comment: That's where your problem is: `toDoList.appendChild(doneButton)`. You added `doneButton` correctly into your `li`, but afterwards by "adding" it to your `toDoList` it got moved into it. Remove the last line of your code and everything should be fine.